# UML design tool and implementation language

Tags: php, jsp, uml

I'm starting a small project for my programming classes and I need a tool to design an UML model of my application, which then I can implement in PHP or JSP.

I downloaded and installed Argo UML and Poseidon Community Edition, both of them seem pretty neat, but I need to choose one over the othed so if you have any experience with both, which one should be better for me? Is there any other choice I should be aware of?

Secondly I use eclipse IDE and I'm a rookie both in PHP and JSP programming so I really don't care about using one or the other, I would like to work with the one who best integrates with my UML design tool choice. Which one would you recommend me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you Argo UML. It has everything you need for a basic project and unlike Poseidon it's opensource. Also, Poseidon code is based on Argo, so there's not much of a difference if you want to switch from one to another if you require some functionality one has and the other doesn't for future projects.

Poseidon has a version specifically designed to build PHP projects which integrates with Eclipse, but unlike Community Edition it's not free of charge.

Also, consider usign UML integration tools from Eclipse's MDT project http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=uml2

About the language, I would go for PHP (If you're using Eclipse I guess you've already heard of Eclipse for PHP) but maybe because I'm more fluent on it I see it easier to set up a WAMP/LAMP server and start coding right away, I don't think it really makes much of a difference to use PHP or JSP as long as you use each language's specific tools properly.